# TSQL: Retrieving a value where a set of values in one table match a set of value in another

Tags: t-sql

Setup: An order has multiple samples, with each sample having a test. A specific combination of tests is a specific testcode. How can I match a set of rows with specific values with another table of specific values to give a single result?

Table: TestCodes

```
ID     TestCode  Test
1        01a       A
2        01b       F
3        02a       A
4        02a       B
5        02b       A
6        02b       C
7        02c       A
8        02c       E
9        03a       A
10       03a       C
11       03a       B
12       03a       D
13       03b       A
14       03b       C
15       03b       E
16       03c       A
17       03c       B
18       03c       E
19       04        A
20       04        C
21       04        B
22       04        D
23       04        E
```

Table: Orders

```
Order Sample Test
1     1      A
1     2      B
1     3      C
1     4      D
1     5      E
2     1      A
2     2      E
```

I can't find a way to return

```
Order TestCode
1     04
2     02c
```

I've tried TSQL views, but can't find a way to compare a set of values in one table to a set of values in another table.

Comment: The problem is defining what criteria you need to get those results. WHy would record one return 04 and record2 return 02C?

Comment: This looks like a question I asked awhile ago.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103829/t-sql-how-do-i-get-the-rows-from-one-table-whose-values-completely-match-up-wit

Comment: @HLGEM It is because the list of tests in Order 1 (see Orders table) is an exact match of the list of tests in TestCode 04 (see TestCode Table). This is the only testcode where this is true for Order 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
SELECT o.OrderId, t.TestCode 
FROM (
    SELECT o.OrderId, t.TestCode, COUNT(*) AS intCount
    FROM Orders o
         INNER JOIN TestCodes t ON t.Test = o.Test
    GROUP BY o.OrderId, t.TestCode
) AS ot
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT OrderId, COUNT(*) AS intCount
        FROM Orders
        GROUP BY OrderId
    ) AS o ON o.OrderId = ot.OrderId
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TestCode, COUNT(*) AS intCount
        FROM TestCodes
        GROUP BY TestCode
    ) AS t ON ot.TestCode = t.TestCode
WHERE o.intCount = ot.intCount
    AND t.intCount = ot.intCount
```

This counts the number of matching test codes for each order, and ensures this number matches both the number of tests for that test code and the number of tests for that order.

It makes the assumption that (TestCode, Test) pairs are unique in TestCodes, and that (Order, Test) pairs are unique in Orders.

Comment: <pre>
Order Sample Test
1     1      A
1     2      B
2     1      A
2     2      C
</pre>
Will that work if theres a record in the orders table like that?

In this situation both orders have the same count of test, but the values for the tests are different.

Comment: Yes it will work in that case. The top query does a count on the INNER JOIN of the two tables. This counts the number of tests they have in common. If the order has exactly two tests, then it can only get an intCount of 2 for one of these test codes, so the other won't match o.intCount. If an order has more than 3 tests, then it could potentially match them both. But in this case, o.intCount != t.intCount, so that will be filtered too.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works well as long as I'm still working with the assumptions you listed above. When I have the order set containing more than one set of test codes (one order, two samples, each sample having three tests) I'm putting a view which counts the samples in place of the Orders table. This collaspses the orginal orders table to fit into the assumtions for the query. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT o.order, t.testcode
from order o
join testcodes t on o.test = t.test

It will only return one per if there's actually one, though, which in this case you don't have.

So you'd have to add in a WHERE clause to, for example, limit the Samples or limit in some other fashion that defines a unique set per order.