# How To Find Perfect Match With Multiple Rows Across Tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to find out which collection of lines from `#Orders` matches with `#Pallets` the best.

With the example below with `@palletId = 1000` as input to the query the results should only be able to match with **'Order2' (100% match)** and **'Order4' (75% match)**. In this case my desired result would be 'Order2'.

Input @palletId = 4000 should have a 100% match to 'Order4' and no other matches.

```
DECLARE @paletId bigint = 1000

CREATE TABLE #Pallets ([PalletId] bigint, [Item] nvarchar(16), [Quantity] int)
CREATE TABLE #Orders ([OrderId] nvarchar(16), [Item] nvarchar(16), [Quantity] int)

INSERT INTO #Pallets ([PalletId], [Item], [Quantity]) VALUES 
(1000, 'item1', 10), 
(1000, 'item2', 10), 
(1000, 'item3', 10),
(4000, 'item1', 10), 
(4000, 'item2', 10), 
(4000, 'item3', 10),
(4000, 'item4', 10)

INSERT INTO #Orders ([OrderId], [Item], [Quantity]) VALUES 
('Order2', 'item1', 10), 
('Order2', 'item2', 10), 
('Order2', 'item3', 10),
('Order1', 'item1', 10),
('Order1', 'item2', 10),
('Order1', 'item3', 5),
('Order3', 'item2', 5),
('Order3', 'item3', 10),
('Order4', 'item1', 10), 
('Order4', 'item2', 10), 
('Order4', 'item3', 10),
('Order4', 'item4', 10),
('Order5', 'item1', 5), 
('Order5', 'item2', 5), 
('Order5', 'item3', 5),

DROP TABLE #ItemTable
DROP TABLE #LocationTable
DROP TABLE #BookingTable 
DROP TABLE #OrderTable
```

Been trying to solve it using the following examples as bases but haven't managed to get the result that I want.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060384/2975371

https://stackoverflow.com/a/104001/2975371

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to make sure, `Order2` contains `item1`, `item2` and `item3` - which means it 
correlates with both instances of `item1/2/3` on the `#Pallets` table? You might also want to table a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51503826/3094533) to a similar question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled and also that the quantities match exactly on the correct item. That's mostly where the trouble comes in. Because order5 would also be a match otherwise but the quantity is only 50% of the required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like a

```
declare @cnt int
select @cnt = count(1) 
from #Pallets
where PalletId = @paletId 


select  top 1 OrderId 
from #Orders o
join #Pallets p on 
    o.Item = p.Item and 
    o.Quantity = p.Quantity and 
    p.PalletId = @paletId 
group by OrderId
order by abs(@cnt - count(PalletId))
```

I just took difference between those two to figure out which one is 'close' to 100%. `abs(@cnt - count(PalletId))` will only return zero if there is a 100% match

Comment: I'll have to do some tests to see if there's a case where it won't work. But at first glance this answer has potential.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
declare @palletId int = 1000;
select OrderId,
       count(p.Item) * 1.0 / count(*) matchLevel
from #Orders o
left join (
    select Item, Quantity
    from #Pallets
    where palletId = @palletId
) p on o.Item = p.Item and o.Quantity = p.Quantity
group by OrderId
```

Which returns:

[image]

Then it's enough to wrap it in query with `top 1` with `order by matchLevel desc`

Comment: This also works really well. But I accepted the other guys answer because it was first.